# How ro change NSTableHeaderView's background color without hiding column's titles?

Tags: xcode, macos, swift, nstableview

I have view-based NSTableView on my Swift OS X app using storyboards, which have 12 columns.

I subclassed my headerview and tried to different things to change background color, but all of them hide my titles also.

This is one of many examples what tried to do:

```
override func drawRect(dirtyRect: NSRect) {
    super.drawRect(dirtyRect)

    // Drawing code here.
    var myLayer = CALayer()
    myLayer.frame = self.frame
    myLayer.backgroundColor = NSColor.greenColor().CGColor
    self.layer?.addSublayer(myLayer)
```

That example on fill whole headerview with greencolor so I tried to tell that I want title's to my columns like that:

```
self.tableView?.tableColumnWithIdentifier("date")?.title = "Date"
```

...But nothing happens. Can anyone please help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In one of my apps I wanted to do (nearly) the same plus a bit more (changing the height of the headerView). Therefore I subclassed **(not the NSTableHeaderView but)** `NSTableHeaderCell`  with my own subclass copying title, font, stringValue etc. from the original cell. (I was not able to do this in IB.)

I first replaced programmatically all cells of the headerView with objects of my class. And here (in the method `- (void)drawWithFrame:(NSRect)cellFrame inView:(NSView *)controlView`) I set the backGroundColor. That works well.

My hint: Do not set the backGroundColor in (a subclass of
`NSTableHeaderView`) but in a subclass of `NSTableHeaderCell`.

Comment: Im noob at coding...when I subclassed NSTableHeaderCeel where I'm supposed to set my title and bgColor?

Comment: I managed to get right result, thanks for your answer, not sure if it's right though...In my ´viewForTableColumn´ I used this to get that working:

Answer (score 0):

```
class ViewController: NSViewController {

@IBOutlet weak var listTableView: NSTableView!

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    
    // Set custom header cell class for each table column
    for aColumn in listTableView.tableColumns {
        let customHeaderCell = CustomHeaderCell(textCell: aColumn.headerCell.stringValue)
        customHeaderCell.font = NSFont.systemFont(ofSize: 13, weight: .regular)
        customHeaderCell.textColor = NSColor.white
        aColumn.headerCell = customHeaderCell
    }
  }
}



class CustomHeaderCell: NSTableHeaderCell {

// Override the initializer to set up your custom properties
override init(textCell: String) {
    super.init(textCell: textCell)
    commonInit()
}

required init(coder: NSCoder) {
    super.init(coder: coder)
    commonInit()
}

// Common initialization code
private func commonInit() {
    // Customize any additional properties or settings here
    self.drawsBackground = true
    self.backgroundColor = NSColor.red
}

// Override the drawing method to customize the appearance
override func draw(withFrame cellFrame: NSRect, in controlView: NSView) {
    // Draw background color
    self.backgroundColor?.set()
    NSBezierPath(rect: cellFrame).fill()

    // Draw separator line
    NSColor.black.withAlphaComponent(0.2).set()
    NSBezierPath(rect: NSRect(x: cellFrame.origin.x, y: cellFrame.origin.y, width: cellFrame.size.width, height: 1)).fill()

    // Draw header text
    let paragraphStyle = NSMutableParagraphStyle()
    paragraphStyle.alignment = .center
    let headerCellText = NSAttributedString(string: stringValue, attributes:
                                            [NSAttributedString.Key.foregroundColor: NSColor.black,
                                             NSAttributedString.Key.font: NSFont.systemFont(ofSize: 13, weight: .regular),
                                             NSAttributedString.Key.paragraphStyle: paragraphStyle,
                                             NSAttributedString.Key.baselineOffset: -6.0
                                            ])
    headerCellText.draw(in: cellFrame)
}
}
```

Ref: https://developer.apple.com/forums/thread/735989

Answer (score 0):

**Add Background and Separator Color**

```
class ViewController: NSViewController {

@IBOutlet weak var listTableView: NSTableView!

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    // Set custom header cell class for each table column
    for aColumn in listTableView.tableColumns {
        let customHeaderCell = CustomHeaderCell(textCell: aColumn.headerCell.stringValue)
        customHeaderCell.font = NSFont.systemFont(ofSize: 13, weight: .regular)
        customHeaderCell.textColor = NSColor.white
        aColumn.headerCell = customHeaderCell
    }
  }
}

class CustomHeaderCell: NSTableHeaderCell {

override func draw(withFrame cellFrame: NSRect, in controlView: NSView) {

    // Draw background color
    NSColor.red.setFill()
    NSBezierPath(rect: cellFrame).fill()

    // Draw separator line
    NSColor.gray.set()
    NSBezierPath(rect: NSRect(x: cellFrame.origin.x + cellFrame.size.width - 1.0, y: cellFrame.origin.y, width: 1.0, height: cellFrame.size.height)).fill()

    // Draw header text
    let interiorFrame = CGRect(x: cellFrame.origin.x, y: cellFrame.origin.y + 4.0, width: cellFrame.size.width, height: 14.0)
    drawInterior(withFrame: interiorFrame, in: controlView)
 }
}
```